# Minimax with tictactoe Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create an AI tictactoe opponent with the minimax algorithm, the problem is that, the AI simply places the O's on the next free space, not an actual good spot. Where am I going wrong here?

```
public static double minimax(String[][] arr, int depth, boolean isMaximizing) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("X", 1);
    map.put("O", -1);
    map.put("Draw", 0);
    double bestScore = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

    String result = evaluateWinner(arr);
    if (!result.equals(" ")) {
        return map.get(result);
    }
    if (isMaximizing) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j].equals(" ")) {
                    arr[i][j] = "X";
                    double score = minimax(arr, depth + 1, false);
                    arr[i][j] = " ";
                    bestScore = Math.max(bestScore, score);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        bestScore = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (arr[i][j].equals(" ")) {
                    arr[i][j] = "0";
                    double score = minimax(arr, depth + 1, true);
                    arr[i][j] = " ";
                    bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return bestScore;
}
```

The code in the main method is :

```
double bestScore = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                                if (arr[i][j].equals(" ")) {
                                    arr[i][j] = "O";
                                    double score = minimax(arr, 0, false);
                                    arr[i][j] = " ";
                                    if (score < bestScore) {
                                        bestScore = score;
                                        iCoordinate = i;
                                        jCoordinate = j;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        arr[iCoordinate][jCoordinate] = "O";
```

Comment: Try to execute your program with a debugger to see where it deviates from your expectations.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, I tried and it infinitely loops, between the minimax and the evaluate winner (if I put the breakpoint at the start of the minimax() (or at least I pressed F8 for 2 minutes straight and it kept spinning and changing the depth (2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3 ,2 ), sth like that. However if I don't put a breakpoint in the methods and keep only one in the main method, the minimax method returns something from time to time, but the result is the same as described before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1 - I strongly advice using `eunm` (or least constants) for the states and/or cell data - String is kind of dangerous:
 `arr[i][j] = "0";` is probably meant to be `... = "O";` 
(not sure since I don't see what is inside `evaluateWinner`)

2 - in main, you start with setting a `"O"` and passing `isMaximizing: false`
but in `minimax`, if `isMaximizing == false` you set another `"0"` (or `"O"`, see previous point)
looks like there is some confusion about `isMaximizing`

3 - check Henry's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67635354/minimax-with-tictactoe-java/67635911#comment119548780_67635354) - most IDE have nice debuggers, best way to check what a program is doing

<sub>4 - as I remember, there is no winning move, if starting with an empty field (assuming opponent does no error - what minimax assumes) - so I suspect that the algorithm will select first position if starting with an empty board

set a "X" in first position and check what happens

*"the only winning move is not to play"* ([WarGames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames)</sub>

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, I tried and it infinitely loops, between the minimax and the evaluate winner (if I put the breakpoint at the start of the minimax() (or at least I pressed F8 for 2 minutes straight and it kept spinning and changing the depth (2, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3 ,2 ), sth like that. However if I don't put a breakpoint in the methods and keep only one in the main method, the minimax method returns something from time to time, but the result is the same as described before.

Comment: as for the other steps, I will try to correct those right now, Thanks a lot!

Comment: ah, I see that now, luckily it was mainly the fault of the typos